# NetLogo move procedures with probability

Tags: netlogo, probability

In my model, I have several different move procedures that an agent can follow. I am trying to use rnd:weighted-one-of-list so that each procedure is followed with a certain probability. I need my probabilities to be assigned via the interface so that I can run BehaviorSpace on the model and test different probabilities for each procedure. However, when trying to create the list for rnd:weighted-one-of-list, I get an error that states I can only use literal values in my list. How could I incorporate interface-defined variables into this procedure?

Cheers

Comment: Can you include some example code showing how you're building your list? It sounds like you may be using the `[ x y z ]` syntax rather than `( list x y z)`, but it's hard to say without seeing the code.

Comment: Hi Luke! Yes that is exactly what I was doing, it worked to use (list (p-elevation) (p-roads) (p-pipelines)....) where each p-variable is the global variable representing the probability of that move procedure being followed. Thanks for your input!